# How to investigate whether number is prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Investigate whether 36611 is prime. Show the first few steps of the procedure.

This is the question. 
Is it enough to show its not divisible by 2, 3, 5 ?
Surely this must not be enough. But how do i do it ? can some one help please ?

Comment: There are various tests for primality, but the simplest is to divide by each prime up to $\sqrt{n}$, which in this case is 191 (rather higher than 5).

Comment: can you send me a link to learn about a primality test?

Comment: This page has a pretty nice overview of the various primality tests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: In this case you are lucky. You just have to probe all primes up to 31 to find the factors 31 and 1181. As $\sqrt{1181}$ is 34.36, it cannot have further factors.